# How do I annotate my usage of "this" to the Closure Compiler in the following Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

I am using the following function to modify the behavior of a specific instance of a Javascript array.  How can I annotate the code for Closure Compiler?  http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler.html Running the code through the compiler produces a "JSC_USED_GLOBAL_THIS" error.

```
function listify(array) {
    array.toString = function() {
        return '[' + this.join(', ') + ']';
    };
    return array;
};
```

It doesn't look like I can use the @extends or @constructor annotation.

I do not want to modify the global Array prototype because that would have unintended side effects when other code is used on the page.  Also, after reading http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/ , I think my approach is the best one for my use case.  The problem is I just don't know how to annotate it to the Compiler

Comment: It says right in the doc you linked that: `To prevent compiler warnings, you must use a @this annotation whenever this appears in a function that is neither a prototype method nor a function marked as a @constructor.`

Comment: @Esailija: Okay. I was not sure the proper way to annotate it.  I would use "{AT}this {Array}" ?

Comment: @Esailija: If you reply back with an answer that fixes the code to include the type definition I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function listify(array) {

    /**
     * Returns the roster widget element.
     * @this {Array}
     * @return {String}
     */
    array.toString = function() {
        return '[' + this.join(', ') + ']';
    };
    return array;
};
```

Comment: Thanks.  I just wasn't sure if there was a more specific JSDoc to use.